# Do i always need put / between origin and branch for git operation?

Tags: git

the `/` between origin and branch 
some time i need put / between origin and branch, somemtime not, could anyone explain me why?

for example here is no `/`

```
git push -u origin branch_name
```

here is with `/`

```
git diff master origin/branch_name
```

Comment: At the moment, your question is much too broad, since it requires a full Git tutorial to answer. You need to narrow down what *precisely* it is that you don't understand. Do you know what a repository is? Do you know what a branch is? Do you know what a ref is? Do you know what a refspec is? Do you know what a refspec looks like? Do you know what `git push` does? Do you know the parameter syntax of `git push`? Have you read its manpage? Do you know what `git diff` does? Do you know the parameter syntax of `git diff`? Have you read its manpage?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I think the question is legitimate. In `git` commands some times you write `origin/master`, but other times you write `origin master`. There is a rationale for that, and understanding it gives you a better insight on how `git` works

Answer (score 1):

One funny thing with `git` is that you cannot look at branches in a remote, only local ones.

When you do `git fetch origin` you are telling `git` to sync all the `X` branches from that remote into local branches named `remotes/origin/X`. Then when you do `git log origin/X` you are actually looking the history of the local branch `remotes/origin/X` (the `remotes` part is assumed).

Some people call these *remote branches*, but they are actually local branches that mimick remote branches.

In the command line, when you name a commit (branch, tag...) and you want to use a *remote branch* (actually a local branch that mimicks a remote one) you must use the `origin/master` format or `remotes/origin/master`.

But if you use a command that uses a remote proper and a *real remote branch* then you use two arguments, one for the remote and another one for the branch or branches. In this case, the real remote branch name will not have the `remote/` part.

For example:

- `git fetch origin master`: Fetch the real remote branch `master` from remote `origin` and clone it into local branch `remotes/origin/master` (with default config).
- `git fetch origin master:foo`: Fetch the real remote branch `master` from remote `origin` and clone it into local branch `foo`.
- `git log origin/master`: Show log of local branch `remotes/origin/master` that will have the same content of remote `master` in `origin` at the time of the previous fetch.
- `git push origin foo:bar`: Upload the local branch `foo` into `origin` as a remote branch named `bar`. If then you do `git fetch origin` you will get a new `remotes/origin/bar` branch identical to `foo`.
- `git push`: If the current branch is configured with upstream, then it will be equivalent to `git push <upstream-remote> <upstream-branch>`.

NOTE: Note the default refspec when you do a `git fetch origin` is `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. See how it makes sense if you remember that the `refs/` part means just the directory of branches and tags, the `heads/` means *local branches*, and `remotes/` means *local clone of remote branches*.

Answer (score 0):

`origin` conventionally refers to the remote from which you cloned your repo. Similarly master conventionally refers to the main branch in your repository.

In the first command, you are asking git to push a branch called `master` **in your local** to a **remote called `origin`**.

In the second command, you are asking git to show you the difference in the branch called `master` **in your local** and a branch called `master` **in a remote called `origin`**.

Contrast it with something like

```
git pull upstream feature1
```

or

```
git diff origin/master upstream/master
```

In the first case, you are pulling from a branch called `feature1` in a remote called `upstream` in to your current local branch.

In the second one, you are checking the difference between the `master` branch in your remote called `origin` and the `master` branch in a remote called `upstream`